# What is the word used when you are aware of a wrong doing or crime, after the event but do nothing about it

Tags: legalese

Looking for a crime or misdoing that has been done and you are aware but chose to do nothing about it. Say in court how would a lawyer explain this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are aware of a crime you committed?  someone you know committed? a stranger committed?   How are aware? Because you saw it? Because you heard about it? From the person who did it? From a witness? From a someone who heard it from someone else?  I saw someone speeding past me on the highway and didn’t call the cops…

Answer (score 4):

[Misprision of felony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misprision_of_felony) consists of

> failing to report knowledge of a felony to the appropriate authorities.

It has been removed as a crime in many jurisdictions.